# How do I redirect replies to my regular phone number?

Tags: twilio

So I use Twilio to send out SMS messages when someone registers a certain form. It sends the first message out but I want to know if it's possible to redirect the message to my actual phone number. For example, the Twilio number sends out the mass text and I want to be able to get any replies to that Twilio number redirected to my real phone number. Is that possible?

I have tried to look at other people's things and have yet to find anyone who has asked my question and I have no idea where to go from here.

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can do that with [Twilio Studio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio)! More details [here](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/115015962887-Forward-Incoming-SMS-Messages-with-Twilio-Studio), but in short:

1. Access the Studio Dashboard in your Studio [Console](https://www.twilio.com/console/studio/dashboard).
2. Make a new Studio flow by clicking the + sign.
3. Pick a name for your flow and click "next".
   [image]"
4. Click "Start from scratch" followed by Next".
   [image]
5. From the "Widget Library" on the right, drag and drop a "Send Message" widget into the flow.
   [image]
6. Click and drag the "Trigger" widget’s "Incoming Message" lead to connect it to the "Send Message" widget.

[image]

7. Click the "Send Message" widget to show the widget's options on the right. Type in the MESSAGE BODY field:

[image]

8. Under the SEND MESSAGE widget options, scroll down to click to expand MESSAGING & CHAT CONFIG. Type in the desired destination (number to forward to with E.164 formatting) in the `SEND MESSAGE TO` field, and then click `Save`.

[image]

9. Select "Publish".

To activate the Studio flow:

1. Visit the Active Numbers page in your [Console](https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/incoming).
2. Select the phone number you want to edit.
3. Scroll to the `Voice & Fax` section to modify the phone number’s routing like so:

[image]

4. Select "Save".

Let me know if this helps! <3 :D